# Additive basis of order 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences

Can we find $\alpha>1$ such that $u=(\lfloor n^\alpha\rfloor)_{n\geqslant0}$ is an additive basis of order $2$ (i.e. $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}, \exists(n,m)\in\mathbb{N}^2, x=u_n+u_m$) ?

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838191/additive-basis-of-order-2), but no response has been provided yet.

Comment: I believe it has been proved that any $\alpha\le5/4$ (perhaps slightly larger) works.

Comment: Do you have a reference about this result ?

Comment: Work of Jean-Marc Deshouillers around 1975-1978, but there is more recent stuff. I can give you the precise ref if you do not find it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to find an article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $1<\alpha<\frac32$, $(\lfloor n^{\alpha}\rfloor)_{n\geqslant0}$ is an asymptotic basis of order 2. I finally found these two articles:

J-M. Deshouillers, [**Un problème binaire en théorie additive**](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa25/aa2549.pdf), Acta Arith. 25 (1974), 393-403

S.V. Konyagin, [**An additive problem with fractional powers**](http://cds.cern.ch/record/720991/files/sis-2004-086.ps), Mathematical Notes, 2003, 73:4, 594–597